# Powershell - rename folder in C:\Windows\

Tags: windows, powershell, directory, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I need some help. I need to rename a few folder in c:\Windows\ but it keeps saying that access is denied. I'm running poweshell as admin.

```
Rename-Item -path 'C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution' -NewName 'C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution.bak'
```

I get the return:

```
Rename-Item : Access to the path 'C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution' is denied.
At line:1 char:2
+  Rename-Item -path 'C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution' -NewName 'C:\Win ...
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution:String) [Rename-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RenameItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
```

Comment: Access is denied. Non-admin users haven't been able to write to the Windows folder for more than a decade now due to UAC. Move out of the 1990s into the modern world.

Comment: @Ken: On Windows NT non-Admin users have never been able to write to the Windows folder. Thus more like 2½ decades.

Comment: http://nl.tinypic.com/r/30jl06t/9

Comment: @Joey: Yep, that would be *more than a decade*.

Comment: @Ken: But not due to UAC.

Comment: Is there a way to tweak around that in poweshell?

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that you are running this cmdlet as consent admin. (UAC)
You have to start your powershell console as administrator. 
(It is not enough to be logged in as administrator.)

Comment: I am running PowerShell as admin.

Comment: I just tried it myself. I am logged in with an account which is member of the local admin group. If I just start the powershell console (the title of the console is "Windows PowerShell") and I run your command, I receive the same error. If I start the Powershell console "as administrator" the title of the console is "Administrator: Windows PowerShell". If I run the command now it is successful.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue:

```
Rename-Item -Path PATH1 -NewName PATH2
```

gave me an `IOException`. I tried the older `REN` command but it is aliased to `Rename-Item` anyway and also did not work.

The only solution that worked for me was to rename it in File Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to close your file explorer and also the IDE file then you can use `Rename-Item PATH1 -NewName PATH2`

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is simply a permission problem, which we can rule out, apparently.

The other likely explanation is that a process still holds an open handle on that folder, or a file within, most likely Windows Update. You'd have to stop the Windows Update service before you do that.

Comment: I do. I'm running a script that handles the services

Answer (score 0):

Try using the -Force switch as well, As long as the PowerShell Session you are running the cmdlet in there shouldn't be any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I think the significant part of the error is where it says IOException:

```
+ CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution:String) [Rename-Item], IOException
```

Check that the folder is not in use, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem before. You need to make sure the directory is not open in any command prompts and you need to turn of the wuauserv service.

You can also use Svish answer in this thread to look for folder locks in the Windows Resource Monitor.
https://superuser.com/questions/117902/find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-or-folder-in-windows